# Fetch Javascript script asynchronously but execute them sequentially

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have two files `one.js` and `two.js`. `two.js` need to be run after `one.js`, but both files can be retrieved in parallel from server.

I achieved this by holding `two.js` response in a variable, then after `one.js` get resolved i used eval to execute `two.js`. Is there any other approach available ?

Comment: I always say, do what works

Comment: Please post your current code. How are you executing *one.js*, also with `eval`?

Comment: Generally you want to be handling this by controlling which *functions* are called in what order, not by controlling the load order of the files they happen to be in.

Answer (score 1):

[The `defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) will:

- Allow scripts to be downloaded in the background
- Delay executing the scripts until after the DOMContentLoaded has fired
- Preserve execution order based on DOM order for multiple defered scripts

```html
<script defer src="one.js"></script>
<script defer src="two.js"></script>
```